# Azure Notification Hub stops sending Apple Push after reinstalling app

Tags: apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

We use Installation model in Azure Notification Hub to send messages to iOS device. InstallationId is created at the first run of the mobile app after it is installed on the device. The mobile app also requests PushToken from APNS. Then the mobile app calls back-end web service with InstallationId and PushToken which calls `NotificationHubClient.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync()` method to register installation in Notification Hub.
After registration the solution works well. The mobile app receives Push notifications as expected.

Issue occurs if I remove the app from mobile device and install it again. Of course in that case new InstallationId is generated and new PushToken is requested from APNS. `NotificationHubClient.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync()` method registers the new installation well. Besides I can send a push message to the mobile app and it is received as expected. But after sending the first message and waiting for several minutes, device stops receiving messages. The device does not receive any following push messages.

The issues is not in APNS as I can send push messages directly to mobile app through APNS service and the mobile app receives them. But device does not receive messages sent with Azure Notification Hub.

This issue does not occur every time. Sometimes removing and installing the mobile app does not lead to the issue.

Does anyone see this issue? How to resolve it? Any workaround?

**UPDATE:**
After additional analysis I have found the following result:

- We completely recreated Notification Hub and uploaded with valid sandbox certificate as recommended, but the issue is still available;
- When the issue happens, Azure Monitor page (in Classic Portal) shows numbers in "Invalid Channel Errors" and "APNS Expired Channel Error" statistics metrics.
- We monitored a `PushChannelExpired` field of installations and found that it is changed not as expected. Below is example:

  1. State 1 (Before reinstalling the app) - As Expected.

`InstallationId = 1, PushChannelExpired = False`.

2. State 2 (After removing and installing the new app) - As Expected.

`InstallationId = 1, PushChannelExpired = False`;

`InstallationId = 2, PushChannelExpired = False`.

3. State 3 (In a minute after sending the first message) - the channel of the second installation marked as expired while the first installation should be marked expired and the second one should be valid.

`InstallationId = 1, PushChannelExpired = False`;

`InstallationId = 2, PushChannelExpired = True`.

4. State 4 (In a minute after sending the second message) - Both installations marked as expired.

`InstallationId = 1, PushChannelExpired = True`;

`InstallationId = 2, PushChannelExpired = True`.

So it seems the issue might be related with `PushChannelExpired` parameter that can be passed to `NotificationHubClient.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync()` method. Now we always pass null to this parameter.

I have found just one short description of this parameter [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621169.aspx): "Put expiredPushChannel to true if pushChannel is changed."

Do you think the issue can be fixed configuring `PushChannelExpired` parameter? If yes, what is the behavior of this parameter?

Comment: Could you go though the [diagnosis guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer) and update the question in case it still doesn't work after and some new information comes up along the way?

Comment: I have added additional information about my research to the topic after reviewing diagnosis guidelines.

Comment: Are you sure you're registering the same tokens when you run it through Azure compared to the direct test you mentioned? If somehow NH gets an incorrect token, it will mark it as expired after being unable to deliver a push.

Comment: I think yes, I register the same token as I receive the first message to device after reinstalling the app. But the device does not receive the second message. So if I registered wrong token, the device didn't receive any message at all.